# How to send packet through a particular interface using scapy, while you are connected to 2 networks?

Tags: python, networking, ping, scapy

I am having two Ethernet card installed on my PC, thus having two interfaces. These two interfaces are connected to Router's two interfaces. Such that:

PC_INT_A --- Network1 ---> ROUTER_INT_1

PC_INT_B --- Network2 ---> ROUTER_INT_2

All the interfaces are fully configured for IPv6 communication. Ping6 is working well through command line.

But when I am trying to send through scapy, while both the networks are connected. I am able to send only first interface in the code. Or I have to disconnect one particular network.

See Below code:

```py
def ns_with_ll(src, dst):
       base = IPv6(src=src, dst=dst, nh=58, hlim=255)
       ns = ICMPv6ND_NS(tgt=dst)
       ll = ICMPv6NDOptSrcLLAddr()
       pkt = base / ns / ll
       return pkt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SRC_A = 'IPV6_ADDR_OF_ETH0'
    SRC_B = 'IPV6_ADDR_OF_ETH1'
    DST_1 = 'IPV6_ADDR_ROUTER_INT_1'
    DST_2 = 'IPV6_ADDR_ROUTER_INT_2'

    ns_a = ns_with_ll(SRC_A, DST_1)
    ns_b = ns_with_ll(SRC_B, DST_2)

    sr(ns_a, iface='eth0')
    sr(ns_b, iface='eth1')
```

The above code gives me output as follows:

```
Begin emission:
*Finished sending 1 packets.

Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
..........................................................................
```

It keeps waiting for the answer from `eth1` interface.

If i change the order of packet sending in code like I am sending packet to `eth1` first. I receive answer from `eth1` and it keeps waiting for answer from `eth0`.

I also check in wireshark, but I do not receive any packet for the second interface.

I have also tried same with sending `ICMPv6EchoRequest`, it behaves in the same way.

Can somebody tell me, how to simultaneously work with multiple networks using scapy. I am using scapy version 2.4.2 with python 3.4?

Answer (score 7):

Hi!

In Scapy, you have two ways of sending packets. The "layer 3 way", which uses the internal routing table (`conf.route`), and the "layer 2 way", which sends a packet on a given interface (`conf.iface` being the default).

`send()` is a "layer 3" function (so it relies on Scapy's routing table), while `sendp()` is a "layer 2" function (it has an `iface=` optional parameter and will use `conf.iface` by default). That's the same for `sr()` and `srp()`.

So in your case, using `srp()` instead of `sr()` and providing the `Ether()` layer should work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
[...]
    srp(Ether() / ns_a, iface='eth0')
    srp(Ether() / ns_b, iface='eth1')
```

Comment: Thanks, figured it out.

Comment: Could we say `conf.iface` equals the MAC address of the interface?